# Finding all possible sums of a number in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Say I have an array of `int[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. I want to display the array, then ask for input to pick a number and print out all possibilities to make that number from that array.

For example, Input is 10
Expected results: 1+9, 2+8... 1+2+7, 1+3+6...1+2+3+5...

```
public class Detyra35 {

    private int[] unsortedNumbers;

    public Detyra35(int[] unsortedNumbers) {
        this.unsortedNumbers = unsortedNumbers;
    }

    public int[] sorted() {
        int[] sortedNumbers = Arrays.copyOf(this.unsortedNumbers, this.unsortedNumbers.length);
        Arrays.sort(sortedNumbers);
        return sortedNumbers;
    }


    public void allSumsOfIndex(int index, int a){
        Detyra35 recursion= new Detyra35(unsortedNumbers);
        for (int i=a; i<index; i++){
            if(unsortedNumbers[i]+(unsortedNumbers[i+1])==index){
                System.out.println(unsortedNumbers[i]+" + " +unsortedNumbers[i+1]+" = "+index);
            }
            recursion.allSumsOfIndex(index,a+1);
        }
    }

    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        //Pass the array into the constructor
        int[] oneToTenArray= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        Detyra35 oneToTen= new Detyra35(oneToTenArray);
        //sort the array and print it so can pick the input
        oneToTen.sorted();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(oneToTenArray));
        System.out.println("Enter the number you want to check all possibilities of sum");
        int choice= scanner.nextInt();
        //call the method to check all sums 0
        oneToTen.allSumsOfIndex(choice,0);
    }
```

What I tried is to call a method and pass the input value. At `allSumsOfIndex` I tried to do something but I can't figure out the if logic, and read online something about recursion but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-backtracking-4/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sums(arr, sum) {
    let pairs = [];
    let numList = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let currNum = arr[i];
        let diff = sum - currNum;
        if (numList.includes(diff)) {
            pairs.push([currNum, diff]);
        }
        numList.push(currNum);
    }
    return pairs;

}
let num = 10;
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(sums(arr,num));
```

Comment: Wrong language.  This question is tagged java, not javascript